# How to write the java code to get contact list from yahoo

Tags: java, contacts, yahoo-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Taking contact list from hotmail gmail yahoo in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397933/taking-contact-list-from-hotmail-gmail-yahoo-in-java)

How to write the java code to get contact list from yahoo

Answer (score 2):

Similar qs asked before .. check that :

[Taking contact list from hotmail gmail yahoo in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397933/taking-contact-list-from-hotmail-gmail-yahoo-in-java)