# Java:Yahoo contacts API

Tags: java, yahoo-api

is there any library or at least some documentation or example on how to import Yahoo! contacts using java and OAuth ?

in my website i need to display/get the yahoo contacts (with oauth)

is there any example.

Comment: Seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397933/taking-contact-list-from-hotmail-gmail-yahoo-in-java

Comment: I am looking for client library like google has Gdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no client library.
You can retrieve contacts in two steps:

Step 1:

Getting 'TOKEN' and 'TOKEN SECRET' of user , using OAuth1. Some libraries are [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) and [signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost) .

Step 2:

After retrieving these tokens you have to get the yahoo id of the user.

Example: (I am using signpost for this)

```
    OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer('YOUR CLIENT ID', 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET');
    URL url = new URL("http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid?format=json");
    HttpURLConnection request1 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret('TOKEN', 'TOKEN SECRET');
    consumer.sign(request1);
    request1.connect();
    String responseBody = convertStreamToString(request1.getInputStream());
```

After this, you have to use the yahoo id of the user retrieved from the user, to get user contacts.

Example:

```
    OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer('YOUR CLIENT ID', 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET');
    URL url = new URL("http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/YAHOO_USER_ID/contacts?format=json");
    HttpURLConnection request1 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret('TOKEN', 'TOKEN SECRET');
    consumer.sign(request1);
    request1.connect();
    String responseBody = convertStreamToString(request1.getInputStream());
```

Method for stream Conversion used above is:

```
    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I have used OAuth2 for importing gmail contacts, can't I use OAuth 2 with signpost?

Comment: @SumitD Yahoo doesn’t support OAuth2, it supports OAuth1 only.